# R data.table generate unique values of each column

Tags: r, data.table, unique

I have a data.table, and I need to generate another data.table that lists only unique values of each column. An example:

From

```
> sourceDT <- data.table(ID = c(1,2,3,4), date = c(ymd("20110101"),ymd("20110101"),ymd("20130101"),ymd("20150101")), text = c("A","B","C","C"))
> sourceDT
   ID       date text
1:  1 2011-01-01    A
2:  2 2011-01-01    B
3:  3 2013-01-01    C
4:  4 2015-01-01    C
```

To

```
> outputDT <- data.table(ID = c(1,2,3,4),date = c(ymd("20110101"),ymd("20130101"),ymd("20150101"),NA), text = c("A","B","C",NA))
> outputDT
   ID       date text
1:  1 2011-01-01    A
2:  2 2013-01-01    B
3:  3 2015-01-01    C
4:  4       <NA>   NA
```

What's the most efficient way of achieving this?

Comment: 200+ columns and 100k+ rows.

Comment: So not unique value combinations? You want the first occurrence of each column kept and the size of data.table maintained?

Comment: @LeGeniusII can you explain the second and third row of output? how are you getting that?

Comment: @zacdav no, not unique value combinations, and yes first occurrence of each column kept and size of data.table maintained.

Comment: @YOLO i don't need unique value combinations, just unique values within each column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

one way you can do: (Though I guess not very Efficient:)

```
sourceDT[,lapply(.SD, function(x)sort(`is.na<-`(x,duplicated(x)),na.last = T))]
   ID       date text
1:  1 2011-01-01    A
2:  2 2013-01-01    B
3:  3 2015-01-01    C
4:  4       <NA>   NA
```

Comment: what is `is.na<-` doing here? Can't understand.

Comment: if a value is duplicated, make it `NA`

Answer (score 1):

This is what I've understood your question to be, the demo you have doesn't quite match what you explained in response to my comment.

This finds duplicates in each column and sets any to NA, this preserves the `data.table` size.

```
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)
sourceDT <- data.table(ID = c(1,2,3,4), date = c(ymd("20110101"),ymd("20110101"),ymd("20130101"),ymd("20150101")), text = c("A","B","C","C"))


for (i in seq_along(sourceDT)) {
  dupes <- which(duplicated(sourceDT[[i]]))
  if (length(dupes > 0)) {
    set(sourceDT, dupes, i, NA)
  }
}

#    ID       date text
# 1:  1 2011-01-01    A
# 2:  2       <NA>    B
# 3:  3 2013-01-01    C
# 4:  4 2015-01-01   NA
```